# Data Inserted Successfully but ajax throwing error

Tags: ajax, web-services

Here is my ajax call function on button click

```
document.getElementById("btnSubmit").onclick = function ()
{
    var txtImageName = $('#txtImageName').val();
    var CategoryId = $('#cmbCategory').val();
    var ImageURL = $('#txtImageURL').val();
    var ImageSource = $('#textEditor').val();
    var value = CKEDITOR.instances['textEditor'].getData()

    alert
    $.ajax({
        url: "UrlwebService.asmx/InsertImage",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { ImageName: txtImageName, ImageUrl3x:ImageURL,ImageSource:value,CategoryId:parseInt(CategoryId) },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success: function (Categories) {               
            // states is your JSON array
               alert(Categories);
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            alert("I'm in terror");
            alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
            alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
};
```

I change content type to application/json it will also throwing me error
and here I'm calling this method.....

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
public void InsertImage(string ImageName, string ImageUrl3x, string     ImageSource, int CategoryId)
{
    var result = ImageRepo.InsertImage(ImageName,ImageUrl3x,ImageSource,CategoryId);
    var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();            
    Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(result));
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: error status 0 response text  empty

Comment: In my experience, you'll see a status of 0 when either doing cross-site scripting (where access is denied) or requesting a URL that is unreachable (typo, DNS issues, etc).

Comment: please refer [this](http://ajaxian.com/archives/xmlhttprequest-and-status-code-0) and [this](http://www.pearweb.com/javascript/XMLHttpRequest.html)

Comment: and some times it give me error or some  times not ? can you evaluate more

Comment: did u refered my links which i have provided  ?

Comment: yes i did but it did'nt clearing me where i'm stuck

Comment: here is my ajax  $.ajax({
            url: "UrlwebService.asmx/InsertImage",
            type: 'POST',
            data:{ImageName: txtImageName, ImageUrl3x:ImageURL,ImageSource:value,CategoryId:parseInt(CategoryId)},dataType:"json",contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
success: function (data) {                              
 console.log(data)
 alert(data);
            }error: function (xhr, err) {
                alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

Comment: Try to change to `contentType:multipart/form-data`

Comment: readystate = 4
status = 500
 
invalidoperationException :Request format is invalid 
at 
system.web.service.protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
system.web.service.protocols.webservieHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

Comment: when i change content type Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded to contentType:multipart/form-data –   it shows me above error

Comment: for Json try this `application/json; charset=utf-8` need your `webconfig` how you are setting this

Comment: when i use content type application/json; charset=utf-8 it gives me error status 500 readystatus 4 insertion faild in db but  when i use this contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" insertion process completed successfully but ajax call error with ready status 0 status 0 response text empty

Comment: Remove `datatype:json`  because ur contenttype is of `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" `